# disable button when class on li doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to prevent the button to be click when there are no item selected in the list. Only enable it when at least 1 in the list have `highlight` class.

HTML

```
<ul class="list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" id="1" value="227">
  <label class="label-list" for="1">Select</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" id="2" value="227">
  <label class="label-list" for="2">Select</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" id="3" value="227">
  <label class="label-list" for="3">Select</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" id="4" value="227">
  <label class="label-list" for="4">Select</label></li>
</ul>

<input type="submit" id="search" class="btn-info" value="search" disabled>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(".list .label-list").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight {background:red;}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5zc6g39g/6/)

Tried to use this script but how do I toggle the attr from disabled to enabled?

```
if( $('.list .label-list').hasClass('highlight') === true ) 
{
 $('#search').addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather test for is `:checked` like

```js
var $checkb = $(".list").find("input[type='checkbox']"),
    $search = $("#search");

$checkb.on("change", function(){
 $search.prop("disabled", !$checkb.is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="224">
      Select
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="225">
      Select
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="226">
      Select
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" value="227">
      Select
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<input type="submit" id="search" class="btn-info" value="search" disabled>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simple count all selected checkbox with this jquery selector

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length
```

this returns the total count of the checkbox selected

just add this event listener which occurs every time a checkbox value is change

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    var disabled = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length ? false: true;
    $("#search").attr('disabled', disabled);
})
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5zc6g39g/12/)

Comment: The true/false return is redundant here.

Comment: @Hosney I don't think this answer deserves down vote just because of that little redundancy

Comment: that wasn't me.. No idea why anyone would downvote the answer.

Comment: Looks like the code disables when at least one is checked? Maybe that's the reason for the downvote. Would be helpful if the downvoter left a comment though.

Comment: @Hosney the problem it self stated the he wanted to prevent the button to be clicked or to disabled it when no checkbox is selected in the list and enable it only if he selected at least 1 checkbox which mean my answer is correct at all

Comment: @Hosney ouch I understand he want the highlight not the checkbox statue true?

Comment: Your demo fiddle seems to work as expected. Just that the true/false need to be swapped in your above answer.

Comment: @Hosney which one really he wanted to check the selected checkbox or the class high light?

Comment: I just need to disable the button when there are no selected checkbox. Already use the other answer though this on work also.

Comment: @MIke maybe this answer deserves upvote thank for upvote